# Primefaces with CDNResourceHandler

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish, cdn, omnifaces

I am pushing my static files to a CND for my web application.  To do so I've used OmniFaces `CDNResourceHandler` that works fine.  Except, my styles do not follow.

I am mapped as so :

```
javax.faces:jsf.js=http://.../jsf.js,
primefaces:primefaces.js=http://.../primefaces.js,
primefaces:jquery/jquery.js=http://.../jquery.js,
primefaces:jquery/jquery-plugins.js=http://.../jquery-plugins.js,
primefaces:idlemonitor/idlemonitor.js=http://.../idlemonitor.js,
        
primefaces-smoothness:theme.css=http://.../theme.css,
primefaces:primefaces.css=http://.../primefaces.css,
styles:main04.css=http://.../main04.css,
```

This works fine, except that my styles are all off.  The rendered result is the same as when `theme.css` AND `primefaces.css` are not loaded.

If I remove these resources as being handled by the `CDNResourceHandler`, the page loads as desired.  I can confirm that these files are being loaded by on the page (`Inspect Element`-> `resources` in web browser show that these are there and loaded).

Has anyone experienced PrimeFaces styles not working through CDN?  Is there a way to get this to work?

My application runs on :

- OmniFaces 1.6
- Primefaces 3.5
- Majorra 2.2
- Glassfish 3.1.2.2 (also tried on Glassfish 4)

#### Edit 1

I have looked into this a bit further and it seems that the css files are not process : something with `#{resources[]}` within the CSS remains as such.  This would be due to the file not meeting the `Faces Servlet` `url-pattern`.  This leads me to believe to achieve what I am looking for I will need the CND resources to be processed...?

#### Edit 2

The weird thing is that the generated HTML has all the loaded resources.  It just seems that the resources (Primefaces styles) are not processed if loaded via CDN.

This is the resources loaded when the page DOES NOT WORK. Everything is functional, except for the basic styles provided by Primefaces.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://.../theme.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://.../primefaces.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://.../main04.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://.../main_compact.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://.../ironmanCompact.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../primefaces.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../idlemonitor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../jquery-plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../jsf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../jquery.ba-postmessage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../tracker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../socialMedia.js"></script>
```

By removing the Primefaces styles from the CDN, this following generated HTML works perfectly and generates the page as it should.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/myapp/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-smoothness" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/myapp/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://.../main04.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://.../main_compact.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://.../ironmanCompact.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../primefaces.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../idlemonitor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../jquery-plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../jsf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../jquery.ba-postmessage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../tracker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../socialMedia.js"></script>
```

Comment: A bit more information on generated HTML output and the HTTP status for all those resource requests would be helpful.

Comment: @BalusC I have posted the generated HTML.  All status are successful (200 OK) and resources load properly.

Comment: Okay, this thus suggests that the problem isn't in the `CDNResourceHandler`. Everything looks fine as to its job. When you open `http://.../theme.css` individually in the webbrowser (copypaste that URL in browser address bar), do you see the right response? (the `theme.css` file's contents).

Comment: Yes, the proper file is loaded - as it would be expected.  Further research into this let me towards the `HeadRenderer` which is specific for Primefaces.  I have tried rewriting one for these files, but to no avail thus far.  Could it be that Primefaces uses that `HeadRenderer` to load it's styles, and thus when using the `CDNResourceHandler` causes a problem with the processing of this?

Comment: The generated HTML output looks fine, so I'm not sure how `HeadRenderer` would play a role here.

Comment: The good news is that I seem to have found the problem.  The file is processed properly by the `Faces Servlet`, but the problem is that all URLs when using `url(#{resource[...]})`, these URLs are relative to the application; ie : `url(/myApp/myLib/file.png)` which is not relative to the new location of the file in the CDN.  The stylesheet loads properly, but the resources to which it is referencing are not available.

Comment: So, the problem is not in the CSS file itself, but in the images referenced in the CSS file? And thus the theme.css and primefaces.css are definitely loaded, on the contrary to what you said in your question? Note: since OmniFaces 1.6 you can use wildcards in CDN mapping like so `primefaces:*=http://.../*`. This way you don't need to explicitly map those images as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the jsf resource lookup by a classic css lookup.
When i externalized my themes this were just two mass-replacements in my ide.

**Instead of:**

```
background:url("#{resource['primefaces:colorpicker/images/colorpicker_select.gif']}");
```

**Use:**

```
background:url("images/colorpicker_select.gif");
```

Or download changed resource and mapping from here:
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=38421